# Add data-th attribute on gridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to add a data-th in a gridView but I don't know how, this attribute is added in a td

Something like this

```
 <tr>
   <td data-th="Movie Title">Star Wars</td>
   <td data-th="Genre">Adventure, Sci-fi</td>
   <td data-th="Year">1977</td>
   <td data-th="Gross">$460,935,665</td></tr>
```

This is my asp.net code 
I tried add `data-th` in the item template and the Templatefield but it isn't working

```
<asp:GridView ID="CerrTick" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" Width="100%"  class="rwd-table" OnPageIndexChanging="CerrTick_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CerrTick_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnC" CommandName="Select" class="button prefix bom" runat="server" Text="Seleccionar" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="N° ticket">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label ID="N_Tick" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("N° ticket") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tecnico"> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Tec" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tecnico") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Empresa">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Emp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("empresa") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="id_ticket" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id_ticket") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Servicio">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="serv" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("servicio") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Code behind RowDataBound

```
protected void CerrTick_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCellCollection cell = e.Row.Cells;
        cell[0].Attributes.Add("data-th", "Movie Title");
        cell[1].Attributes.Add("data-th", "Genre");
        cell[2].Attributes.Add("data-th", "Year");
        cell[3].Attributes.Add("data-th", "Gross");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid doing it in the code behind, you could build the table using a ListView or Repeater and dynamically assign the data attribute. I'm doing something similar, although the data attribute is assigned to the label inside the gridview rather than the cell itself.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("value") %>' data-frequency='<%#Eval("frequency") %>' />
```